# Is it possible to convert an array of json objects to a sequelize query?

Tags: node.js, sequelize-typescript

I'm receiving an array of JSON objects from the client and I need to dynamically convert it to a `sequelize` query

I tried using switch cases such as case 'and' will make object.other = [op.and] and so on. But it doesn't work.

I expect to receive something like this:

```
[
 {
   other: "",
   column: "name",
   value: "Kevin"
 }
 {
   other: "and",
   column: "id",
   value: "10"
 }
]
```

and it should convert to

```
Model.findAll({
 where: {
  [Op.and]: [{name : 'Kevin'},{id: 10}] 
 }  
})
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add the code snippet which you tried in your question. Also, what all operators you want to support in the query? Will that always be `and`?

Comment: @AbhasTandon the operator can be 'and' or 'or'

Comment: How do you plan to handle difference between `A == B or (C == D AND E == F)` and `(A == B or C == D) AND E == F`  with your current data structure?

Comment: I thought of adding 2 key value pairs (one for left parenthesis, one for right parenthesis) and just check the value of the number of parenthesis and group them accordingly.